# Spark/Scala parallel write to redis

Tags: scala, apache-spark, redis, spark-redis

Is it possible to write to Redis in parallel from spark?

(Or: how to write tens of thousands of keys/lists quickly from spark)

Currently, I'm writing to Redis by key in sequence, and it's taking *forever*. I need to write about 90000 lists (of length 2-2000). Speed is extremely important. Currently, it's taking on the order of 1 hour. Tradition benchmarks of Redis claim thousands of Redis writes per second, but in my pipeline, I'm not anywhere near that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As I asked you on twitter - what is your setup? A single redis? A redis cluster? RLEC?

Comment: Just using a single Redis actually. Running in a mesos cluster.

Comment: The connector is optimized to run over a redis cluster where every spark node has a local redis node, and the partitioning functions match so that you'll always write to local redis. How many spark nodes are you running?

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer four nodes. I suppose we could try running a redis local to each node. How would we read keys from a single ip? We could do a rebalance probably.

Comment: Do you use pipeline for sending command to Redis? Pipeline is very fast compared to one by one sending commands.

Answer (score 2):

A single Redis instance runs in one thread so operations are inherently sequential. If you have a Redis cluster then the instance to which a datum is written depends on a [hash slot](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec) calculated from the key being written. This hash function (amongst other things) ensures that the load gets distributed across all the Redis instances in the cluster. If you cluster has N instances, you have (almost) at most N parallel writes that you can execute. This because each cluster instance is still a single thread. A reasonable Spark Redis connector should exploit the cluster efficiently.

Either way, Redis is really quick, especially if you use [mass inserts](http://redis.io/topics/mass-insert).